# Chinese Remainder Theorem Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I’m working on some Chinese Remainder problems and it doesn’t seem like I have the procedure down correctly. I'll list the steps I’m taking so hopefully someone can spot what it is I’m doing wrong.

> Find the least nonnegative solution of each system of congruences below.
>
> $x \equiv 3 \space mod \space 4$
>
> $x \equiv 2 \space  mod \space 5$

Since the mod values are relatively prime, I preformed the following procedure described in my textbook. Let $M = m_{1} \cdot m_{2} \cdot \cdot \cdot m_{n}$ and $M_{i} = \frac{M}{m_{i}}$

> $M = (4) \cdot (5) = 20$
>
> $M_{1} = \frac{20}{4} = 5$
>
> $M_{2} = \frac{20}{5} = 4$

Next solve the congruence $M_{i} x_{i} \equiv \text{1 mod} \space m_{i}$ for $x_{i}$

> $5x_{1} \equiv \text{1 mod} \space 4$ $\Longrightarrow$ $x_{1} \equiv 1 \space \text{mod} \space 4$
>
> $2x_{2} \equiv \text{1 mod} \space 5$ $\Longrightarrow$ $x_{2} \equiv 3 \space \text{mod} \space 5$

Finally solve for x, where x is defined in the following way: $x = b_{1} \cdot M_{1} \cdot x_{1} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + b_{n} \cdot M_{n} \cdot x_{n}$

> $x = (3 \cdot 5 \cdot 1) + (2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3) \space \text{mod} \space 20$
>
> $x = 19 \space mod \space 20$

Now this final value indicates that any positive integer congruent to 19 modulo 20 solves the given system of equations. However, the answer at the back of my textbook is 7 which isn't congruent to 19 modulo 20.

Any help with where I'm going wrong would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your solution is incorrect since $x \equiv 19 \pmod{20}$ gives $x \equiv 4 \pmod {20}$. You need to solve for $$\color{blue}{4 x_2 \equiv 1 \pmod5}$$ and not $$\color{red}{2x_2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5}$$ Hence, you will get that
$$\color{blue}{x_2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5}$$ and not $$\color{red}{x_2 \equiv 3 \pmod 5}$$ The rest of your derivation is correct. Make the above correction and you will get the right answer.

Comment: Thanks! those small typos will get you every time!

Answer (score 2):

The second case should be $x_2\cdot \frac{20}5\equiv1\pmod 5$

$\implies 4x_2\equiv1\pmod 5\implies -x_2\equiv1\pmod 5\implies x_2\equiv-1\pmod 5\equiv4\pmod 5$

So, $x\equiv3\cdot5\cdot1+2\cdot4\cdot4\pmod{20}\equiv47\equiv7\pmod{20}$

Answer (score 1):

I noticed something very interesting: there are many implementations of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

---

**Chinese Remainder Theorem**:

A theorem for solving a system of linear congruences, which come in the form

$\displaystyle x\equiv n_1\pmod{m_1}$

$\displaystyle x\equiv n_2\pmod{m_2}$

$\displaystyle \vdots$

$\displaystyle x\equiv n_k\pmod{m_k}$

Where $\displaystyle k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\displaystyle m_1, m_2\cdots m_k$ are pairwise coprime, then $\displaystyle x_0=B_1X_1n_1+B_2X_2n_2+\cdots+B_kX_kn_k$ where $\displaystyle B=\prod_{i=1}^{k}m_i$ and $\displaystyle B_k=\frac{B}{m_k}$ and $\displaystyle X_k$ is defined so that $\displaystyle B_kX_k\equiv1\pmod{m_k}$.

The smallest positive integer solution $\displaystyle x_1$ is defined such that $\displaystyle x_0\equiv x_1 \pmod{B}$

---

For this system where it is

$\displaystyle x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$

$\displaystyle x \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$

$\displaystyle B = 4\times5 = 20$

$\displaystyle B_1=\frac{20}{4}=5$, $\displaystyle B_2=\frac{20}{5}=4$

$\displaystyle 5X_1\equiv1\pmod{4} \iff X_1\equiv1\pmod{4}$, $\displaystyle X_1=1$

$\displaystyle 4X_2\equiv1\pmod{5}$, $\displaystyle X_2=4$

$\displaystyle x=5\times1\times3+4\times4\times2=47$

$\displaystyle 47 \equiv 7\pmod{20}$

That is why your textbook says the answer if $\displaystyle 7$.