# System of Linear Congruences and Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way to find the solution to $x \equiv 3 $ (mod $4)$ and $x \equiv 10$ (mod $35$) without trial and error in the scope of elementary number theory? Is there a trivial solution you can immediately see from this? (How would you guess that case?) One solution is 115, but I got this from guessing.

EDIT: To clarify, let me give an example of a problem I did. I solved

$x \equiv 3 $ (mod $4)$,
$x \equiv 5 $ (mod $21)$, and $x \equiv 7 $ (mod $25)$ by solving the first two congruences first: $x \equiv 3 $ (mod $4)$,
$x \equiv 5 $ (mod $21)$. I guessed that $x = 47$ would work in both by using the first congruence with trial and error. Would there have been an easier way to do this? From this, would there be a trivial answer to the original system provided?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I would think that Chinese Remainder Theorem is within the scope of elementary number theory.

Comment: I edited the question with an example.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of solving a system of congruences presented in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209672/find-all-solutions-to-system-of-congruence).  Here is how you can solve your system by solving each equation successively, as in the second answer in the linked post.

Since $x \equiv 10 \pmod{35}$, then $x = 10 + 35a$ for some integer $a$.  Substituting this into the first equation yields
$$
3 \equiv x = 10 + 35 a \equiv 2 + 3a \pmod{4} \implies 1 \equiv 3a \implies 3 \equiv a \, .
$$
Then $a = 3 + 4b$ for some $b$, so
$$
x = 10 + 35a = 10 + 35(3 + 4b) = 115 + 140b
$$
and varying $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ produces all possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform the *extended Euclidean algorithm* to have a 
*Bézout's relation* between $4$ and $35$: $\;4u+35v=1$. Then
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv 3\mod 4\\x\equiv 10\mod 35\end{cases}\iff x\equiv 10\cdot 4u+3\cdot 35v\mod 4\cdot 35$$